# How to configure a connection to MySql with nhibernate in net core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, nhibernate

I am programming the connection to the database for a api in net core. I decided to inhibit but I can not connect to the mysql database, it's a local configuration, what I have is the following

that is my CreateSessionFactory

private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {

```
        string connection = "server='localhost';Database='equalsbd';UserId='root';Password='123456';port=3304";

        var db = MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connection);

        return Fluently.Configure().Database(db)
                     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf
                      <SessionNHibernate>()).BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

this is my full class

public class SessionNHibernate
{

```
private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
private static ISession session = null;

private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
{
    get
    {
        if (SessionFactory == null)

            sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;

    }

}

public static ISession Session
{
    get { return session; }
}
public static ISession OpenSession() {
    try
    {
        session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        return session;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var p = ex;
        return session;
    }
}

public static void CloseSession()
{
    session.Close();
}
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    try
    {


        string connection = "server='localhost';Database='equalsbd';UserId='root';Password='123456';port=3304";

        var db = MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connection);

        return Fluently.Configure().Database(db)
                     .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf
                      <SessionNHibernate>()).BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return null;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the first change I made was to modify

```
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
```

by

```
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = null;
```

to prevent confusions

the second was to update the usermap by changing its private property to protected, this being private for some reason does not allow the connection to read the attributes

leaving in this way

this

```
 public class Usuarios 
{
    public virtual long idUsuarios { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Usuario { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Perfiles_idPerfiles { get; private set; }

   public static List<Usuarios> ListaUsuario() {

        using (var session = SessionNHibernate.OpenSession() )
        {
            return session.Query<Usuarios>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

by the correct way

```
  public class Usuarios 
{
    public virtual long idUsuarios { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Usuario { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Perfiles_idPerfiles { get; protected set; }

   public static List<Usuarios> ListaUsuario() {

        using (var session = SessionNHibernate.OpenSession() )
        {
            return session.Query<Usuarios>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

with this your connection to mysql will work or with any other database